# Is there SDK for Agent event streams data model?

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-connect

We would like to consume AWS connect events.
I was hoping there is sdk for [events described](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/agent-event-stream-model.html#AgentEvent) but we cannot find anything in [aws java skd](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/connect/model/package-summary.html) nor [kotlin sdk](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/kotlin/api/latest/connect/aws.sdk.kotlin.services.connect.model/index.html)

Where could we find SDK that supports Agent and Contact events as they are coming from Kinesis stream?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Connect Agent events are published to an Amazon Kinesis Data Stream (KDS). The KDS is just a storage location for the data, which is essentially a JSON representation of each event. You need to use the Kinesis Client Library (KCL), Kinesis Firehose, or Lambda to get the JSON event data from the KDS. Each KDS record has a payload where you will find the the event JSON. The JSON payload will have properties as described in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/agent-event-stream-model.html).

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering if there is already SDK i that is mapping events to java objects.

Comment: There is not, unfortunately. Since the data is JSON, you can easily use a parser to convert it to a POJO in your application.